# MongoDB Connection URL not connecting to database

Tags: url, connection

My nodejs server's  config.js accesses the mongoDB using

'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB',

When I browse my angular web client using :

https://aws_ip_address/home/app/index.html

I was able to load my static pages but data from the MongoDB was not retrieved.

Looking at the developer tools I saw the following error message:

Failed to load source: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localhost:3443/aliments

when I test localhost:3443/aliments on the browser, I got

This site can't be reached

localhost refused to connect.

But if I replaced the word localhost with the ip address of my aws instance it was able to retrieve my data from the browser.

The following are all installed on the same instance on aws:

MongoDB, node js server, angular web client.

How should I change my config.js file to access my MongoDB running on the aws?
I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform port-forwarding on the AWS console for your instance i.e you need to white-list the ports that are being used in your app.

On your AWS-EC2 instance go-to the security groups and add a new inbound rule to define a new custom TCP/IP rule for a port that will make it accessible from the outside.

Comment: My security groups Inbound has (1) Custom TCP Rule for port 3443 (2) HTTP for port 80 (3) SSH for port 22 (4) Custom TCP Rule for 27017 (5) Custom TCP Rule for 3000. Am I missing out anything?

Comment: I tried to change my ipbind statement in the /etc/mongd.conf file to ipbind: 0.0.0.0 and it worked one time and then did not work again. Same problem of Failed to load resource...localhost:3443/aliments. What exactly is the cause of the problem?

Comment: It seems like your OS is firewall protected, try commenting out the bindIp: 0.0.0.0 and also disabling the iptables.